# iOS: How to prevent multiple taps of button from creating multiple new instances

Tags: ios, instance

Just noticed something peculiar with my app. Whenever I tap one of the bar buttons to open a popover viewcontroller, if I tap it again it simply opens another instance of that vc (I can keep doing this).

How do I stop this? Should I use a boolean to disable the button when the boolean is active and then somehow reset it when the user closes the VC by other means (such as tapping part of the screen that isn't the same VC)?

Tried the boolean suggestion:

In my prepareForSegue method I have the following:

```
  if(isActive==false){
        InformationViewController *informationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        informationViewController.delegate = self;
            isActive = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may no longer be important, but I would recommend the boolean solution you proposed with one modification. If you move the

```
isActive = true;
```

statement to viewWillAppear, I'm pretty sure the button will remain disabled until the modal view closes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest using a global bool value. Set the variable to true when the button is pressed.

In the function that creates the instance, check to make sure that the variable is false before creating the instance.

Once the instance is deleted, set the variable back to false.

Psuedo-code (in C++):

```
bool isActive = false;
void CreateInstance()
{
    if (isActive == false)
    {
        -- code
        isActive = true;
    }
}

void InstanceDestroyed()
{
    -- code
    isActive = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it but sadly it won't work for me (I'm sure I've done something wrong).
EDIT: Putting the code in the original post.

Comment: I read your edit, but you never set `isActive` to false when the instance is destroyed.

Comment: Oh true, but shouldn't the current code stop the instance spam anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Logically, it should work, but I am unfamiliar with iOS development, so I can't help you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the button to disable once the view appears, and then add code in your popover view to:

a) send a notification using Notification Center once the popover is dismissed to be "caught" by the view that holds the button and re-enable the button, or...

b) use the delegation pattern using a protocol to handle the re-enabling of the button once the popover view is dismissed.

These methods might require a little bit more work, but I try not to use any global variables in a MVC pattern.

Comment: I'll look into it. I'm familiar with delegation so I'll give that a try. Any reason to choose Notification Center over delegation? Thanks

EDIT: I've been looking at some non-storyboard tutorials which use popovercontrollers as wrappers - this seems to fix the issue. Any idea how I can do this with storyboards? Disabling the button temporarily seems okay but not 100% right.

Comment: Here is a pretty good article about pros/cons using notifications, delegates and Key value observing:  http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/
Sorry I can't really help you with the storyboards, as my current apps don't use them.  Sounds like a great excuse to create one now to learn 'em.